# C: Why am i getting Segmentation fault in one case and not in the other?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i am new to C so i believe there is a rookie mistake somewhere in my code due to lack of fundamentals in pointers and memory allocation.

I have a binary file representing numerical data, and i am trying to read and store that data.
This is first part of the code that opens the file, reads fisrt few numbers in file which are than used to allocate enough memory for the struct emxArray_real_T.

Struct:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
    real_T *data;
    int32_T *size;
    int32_T allocatedSize;
    int32_T numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
}
```

First part of main:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h> /*atoi*/
# include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

//Variable declaration
unsigned short numOfSums;
unsigned long chSum, countRSN, countPeriods;
int i,j;
FILE *file;

//Open file
file = fopen("testBin.bin","rb");

//Read first number that tells how many items to skip
fread(&numOfSums, 2, 1,file);
//Skip that many items
for (i=0;i<numOfSums;i++){
    fread(&chSum,4,1,file);
}
//Read next two numbers
fread(&countRSN,4,1,file);
fread(&countPeriods,4,1,file);

//Allocate enaugh space based on the size of countRSN and countPeriods
struct emxArray_real_T* Sa_1 = malloc(sizeof(*Sa_1)*1);
assert(Sa_1 != NULL);
Sa_1->data=malloc(sizeof(real_T)*countRSN*countPeriods);
Sa_1->size=malloc(sizeof(int32_T)*2);
Sa_1->allocatedSize=(sizeof(int32_T)*1);
Sa_1->size[0]=countRSN;
Sa_1->size[1]=countPeriods;

struct emxArray_real_T *Sa_2;
Sa_2=(struct emxArray_real_T*)malloc(sizeof(struct emxArray_real_T)*1);
assert(Sa_2 != NULL);
Sa_2->data=(real_T*)malloc(sizeof(real_T)*countRSN*countPeriods);
Sa_2->size=malloc(sizeof(int32_T)*2);
Sa_2->allocatedSize=(sizeof(int32_T)*1);
Sa_2->size[0]=countRSN;
Sa_2->size[1]=countPeriods;

struct emxArray_real_T *sVs30;
sVs30=(struct emxArray_real_T*)malloc(sizeof(struct emxArray_real_T));
sVs30->data=malloc(sizeof(real_T)*countRSN);
sVs30->size=malloc(sizeof(int32_T)*1);
sVs30->allocatedSize=(sizeof(int32_T)*1);
sVs30->size[0]=countRSN;
```

Here is the problem. If i try to store my data and transpose it, because it's not in the right order, i get Segmentation fault,

```
for (i=0;i<countRSN;i++){
    for (j=0;j<countPeriods;j++){
        fread(&Sa_1->data[countRSN*j+i],8,1,file);
    }
}
```

if i just try like this, it is working:

```
for (i=0;i<countRSN*countPeriods;i++){
    fread(&Sa_1->data[i],8,1,file);
}

.
.
.

fclose(file);

free(Sa_1);
free(Sa_2);
free(sVs30);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How big are `countRSN` and `countPeriods`? Does the product fit into an `int`?

Comment: One is couple of thousand and the other couple of hundred.

Comment: You should write `fread(&numOfSums, sizeof numOfSums, 1,file)` instead of assuming the size of data types.

Comment: Never assert that malloc does not return null.  `assert` is not a replacement for error checking.  That is not its purpose.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for notecing, i just tried everything and put that line in attempt to see if malloc returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

With every call to `fread` you read 8 bytes and write them to the array. It seems to me you are storing them in the correct position. A Segmentation fault would have to be expected if `sizeof(real_T)` is smaller than 8.

If `sizeof(real_T)` is smaller than 8, say it's size 4*, `&Sa_1->data[countRSN*countPeriods-1]` will write 4 of the 4 bytes in a valid location, and the other 4 bytes will be written outside of the allocated range.

Why does the code crash in one case and not the other? First, by accessing unallocated memory you are in the territory of undefined behaviour. The program doesn't need to behave in a well defined way anymore. Second, `fread` doesn't write to the buffer if the file stream has already reached the end. The code which works in  your example only writes to the last address if the file is long enough.

*In Matlab, `real_T` is either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on defines. If it's 4 bytes, the code given by the op should throw a segfault.

Comment: sizeof(real_T) is 8 bytes. I only read maybe 10% of the binary file so file is long enough not to reach its end. In example that works, last number i read is exactly where i want to stop.

Comment: If that is true, then the problem is somewhere other than the for loop. Did you by chance attach a debugger, or used printf to find out which line throws the segfault?

Comment: GDB did not tell me on which line segfault was thrown. I than stepped through my code line by line and segfault was thrown in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for updating. In that case my bet is still on real_T being 4 bytes rather than 8, maybe because of a rogue header that redefines it? How about you use real64_T instead, since they should be the same anyway? As a library function, `fread` should be fine, so the segfault should be because you feed the fread method an invalid buffer. That's unless you are accessing a custom `fread` function. Also, is there a chance that "countRSN" or "countPeriods" are reassigned between the allocation and the loop?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. There is no way that countRSN, countPeriods are reassigned, but i will look in to sizeof(real_T) again.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming size of types. Use `sizeof` everywhere you use 4, 2, 8 etc. Also make sure the fread will work with short int, which I doubt

Comment: I replaced it with sizeof(type) but still get Segmentation fault for the first example.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct emxArray_real_T* Sa_1 = malloc(sizeof(*Sa_1)*1);
```

To

```
struct emxArray_real_T* Sa_1 = malloc(sizeof(struct emxArray_real_T));
```

Comment: Sadly, get the same result.

Comment: Also, you should be free'ing all other memory allocated before free'ing Sa_1, Sa_2, sVs30.

Comment: Why would data[countRSN] be crossing the boundary? Is not the boundary of Sa_1->data defined by memory allocation which is of size countRSN*countPeriods*sizeof(real_T).